# SD card socket just need to wire with pull-up resistors?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, pullup, pins, sd

I have a question about Micro SD card and STM32F446RE wiring issues. I saw this schematic from ST forum. I would like to ask, when I wiring STM32F446RE with SD card socket (I mean connection part), just need to wire with pull-up resistors?

Or something different is needed? Also, this schematic is work well?

[image]

https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000DjBwK/wiring-micro-sd-card-slot-to-mcu

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The pullups are not necessary, I've never used them. They would be necessary if you had unusually power supply sequencing or if the GPIO's could go into an undetermined state if the STM32 Vcc was down but the SD card was not.

You shouldn't have to use pull ups if the STM GPIO's are using push-pull and the STM32 I/O Vcc is 3.3V.

Comment: I would have to disagree with this answer. I recall the pull-ups are mandatory, as the cards can be first enumerated in open-drain mode, which won't work unless there are pull-up resistors. They also keep the bus state well-defined during turnaround periods and when MCU is in reset, still booting, or being programmed before IO is initialized. For reference, see Nexperia appnote AN10911.

Answer (score 0):

The pull-ups are expected to be present in the host. 10k is the minimum value for SD cards, and for MMC cards the minimum value is 50k. It might be a good idea to make the resistance slightly higher than 10k, or slightly higher than 50k if MMC cards can be used in the system.